# toggle buttons using tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is simple. I have two buttons in a web page. They are sitting closely.
Currently I use mouse to click one of them then doing something.
Can we just use keyboard such as TAB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tab to press buttons will completely break accessiblity on you websites and will effectively drive away any keyboard users from your website, it's an *awful* practice.

In any case, you might want to capture events for '*' using jquery:

```
$('*').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 9)
    //stuff
})
```

Though I'd strongly recomend agaist doing this; never override what keys such as tab do, you'll create huge accessiblity issues.

[**EDIT**]:
Adding the event to `document` might be more efficient:

> If key presses anywhere need to be caught (for example, to implement
>   global shortcut keys on a page), it is useful to attach this behavior
>   to the document object. Because of event bubbling, all key presses
>   will make their way up the DOM to the document object unless
>   explicitly stopped.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery would be perfect for this just bind the key to that button. something like this.

```
$('your selector here').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which == '9'){
     //do your stuff here
     }
});
```

I think 9 is the correct charcode for tab but you might need to check that. and make sure you do this inside of $(document).ready();

Answer (score -1):

Yes, hit `Tab` until the button has a dotted border to indicate focus, then you can hit `Enter` or `Space` to click the button.

E.g. Button 2 has the focus here and pressing `Space` or `Enter` would "click" it:

[image]

Comment: Since he's using javascript and jquery, it's quite clear he wants to bind the key to the button, not know how to use tab to navigate through them.